# Java RXTXcomm lib to connect to /dev/ttyACM0

Tags: java, serial-port, communication, rxtx

I'm using RXXTX java lib to connect to serial ports. I'm using this lib with no problems connecting to /dev/ttyUSB0 (1,2,3,etc).

But when I want to connect to /dev/ttyACM0 the port its not found.

```
CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/ttyACM0");
```

the Exception is thrown:

> gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
>     at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:218)

I already listed all the ports but no success.

Comment: http://pblog.ebaker.me.uk/2011/09/processing-usb-ports-devttyacm0.html and http://mailman.qbang.org/pipermail/rxtx/2007-June/9733356.html

Comment: You can find the solutions to the problem in the given links: - http://pblog.ebaker.me.uk/2011/09/processing-usb-ports-devttyacm0.html - http://mailman.qbang.org/pipermail/rxtx/2007-June/9733356.html

Answer (score 3):

Processing and USB ports /dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyACM1, ....
http://pblog.ebaker.me.uk/2011/09/processing-usb-ports-devttyacm0.html

> Processing doesn't like reading Linux USB devices like /dev/ttyACM0 or
>   /dev/ttyACM1.
>
> The solution is easy, just symlink the devices  like this...
>
> ln -s /dev/ttyACM[x] /dev/ttyS8[x]
>
> You can put any number after the ttyS, although it is possible that
>   ttyS0 and other low numbers are defined, numbers in the eighties are
>   (almost) guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openhab/f-gVkwJg-hg

> update your startup script to include "->Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=/dev/ttyACM0" in the Java command line